# Ggpredict over fitting causing trend line to begin in an odd place

Tags: ggplot2, lme4

I am not entirely sure what I am doing wrong/what to look up. My objective is to use ggpredict and ggplot to display the relationship between time and the proportion of years burnt. I'm guessing it is something to do with the time variable being log transformed?

```
library(lme4);library(ggplot2);library(ggeffects);library(dplyr)
data = read.csv('FtmpAllyrs10kmC.csv')
```

This is what the data looks like:

```
    structure(list(Observ = c(5208, 2828, 1664, 578, 18, 1644, 4741, 
751, 689, 3813, 1464, 438, 1553, 4752, 4960, 376, 2482, 1811, 
5682, 5441, 4505, 2281, 2103, 2993, 562, 4297, 3592, 5148, 3793, 
1621, 1912, 1627, 1737, 4976, 2173, 5132, 5758, 2756, 1789, 5666, 
2628, 2593, 794, 5779, 5158, 3123, 4986, 676, 4200, 2442, 2751, 
4330, 1802, 2020, 2500, 1056, 959, 3290, 4303, 247, 5586, 922, 
1049, 2432, 2076, 2560, 1369, 3636, 3722, 4137, 1561, 4915, 2515, 
3034, 5547, 1491, 1247, 4116, 455, 4687, 1697, 5329, 21, 5724, 
3701, 5697, 2938, 1721, 61, 998, 4304, 5798, 651, 910, 2689, 
3986, 2908, 5753, 2574, 2345, 1940, 4317, 4588, 2179, 665, 4133, 
749, 3977, 3134, 4190, 3985, 4937, 2473, 3238, 4987, 3915, 4261, 
3521, 2736, 3665, 1797, 5692, 5578, 4087, 2011, 903, 889, 1523, 
3396, 2291, 5269, 3644, 3403, 4814, 4618, 16, 77, 5385, 2842, 
5816, 2015, 1443, 3183, 3331, 4977, 5380, 989, 4918, 740, 4637, 
887, 1557, 4295, 4673, 1918, 5662, 4167, 1384, 3441, 614, 2360, 
780, 661, 1267, 2018, 1906, 3402, 677, 5218, 2830, 4979, 3984, 
4924, 1125, 2640, 986, 1885, 2573, 5300, 2398, 4832, 4816, 3738, 
3276, 3830, 2425, 2054, 4273, 5607, 1678, 378, 1158, 510, 2210, 
2399, 1952, 2909, 4945, 2659, 2642), yrblock15 = c(2015, 2010, 
2007, 2005, 2004, 2007, 2014, 2005, 2005, 2012, 2007, 2004, 2007, 
2014, 2015, 2004, 2009, 2008, 2016, 2016, 2014, 2009, 2008, 2010, 
2005, 2013, 2011, 2015, 2012, 2007, 2008, 2007, 2007, 2015, 2008, 
2015, 2016, 2010, 2007, 2016, 2009, 2009, 2005, 2016, 2015, 2010, 
2015, 2005, 2013, 2009, 2010, 2013, 2008, 2008, 2009, 2006, 2006, 
2011, 2013, 2004, 2016, 2006, 2006, 2009, 2008, 2009, 2007, 2012, 
2012, 2013, 2007, 2014, 2009, 2010, 2016, 2007, 2006, 2013, 2005, 
2014, 2007, 2015, 2004, 2016, 2012, 2016, 2010, 2007, 2004, 2006, 
2013, 2016, 2005, 2006, 2009, 2012, 2010, 2016, 2009, 2009, 2008, 
2013, 2014, 2008, 2005, 2013, 2005, 2012, 2010, 2013, 2012, 2014, 
2009, 2011, 2015, 2012, 2013, 2011, 2010, 2012, 2007, 2016, 2016, 
2013, 2008, 2006, 2005, 2007, 2011, 2009, 2015, 2012, 2011, 2014, 
2014, 2004, 2004, 2015, 2010, 2016, 2008, 2007, 2011, 2011, 2015, 
2015, 2006, 2014, 2005, 2014, 2005, 2007, 2013, 2014, 2008, 2016, 
2013, 2007, 2011, 2005, 2009, 2005, 2005, 2006, 2008, 2008, 2011, 
2005, 2015, 2010, 2015, 2012, 2014, 2006, 2009, 2006, 2008, 2009, 
2015, 2009, 2014, 2014, 2012, 2011, 2012, 2009, 2008, 2013, 2016, 
2007, 2004, 2006, 2005, 2008, 2009, 2008, 2010, 2014, 2009, 2009
), circleID = c(258, 128, 314, 128, 18, 294, 241, 301, 239, 213, 
114, 438, 203, 252, 10, 376, 232, 11, 282, 41, 5, 31, 303, 293, 
112, 247, 442, 198, 193, 271, 112, 277, 387, 26, 373, 182, 358, 
56, 439, 266, 378, 343, 344, 379, 208, 423, 36, 226, 150, 192, 
51, 280, 2, 220, 250, 156, 59, 140, 253, 247, 186, 22, 149, 182, 
276, 310, 19, 36, 122, 87, 211, 415, 265, 334, 147, 141, 347, 
66, 5, 187, 347, 379, 21, 324, 101, 297, 238, 371, 61, 98, 254, 
398, 201, 10, 439, 386, 208, 353, 324, 95, 140, 267, 88, 379, 
215, 83, 299, 377, 434, 140, 385, 437, 223, 88, 37, 315, 211, 
371, 36, 65, 447, 292, 178, 37, 211, 3, 439, 173, 246, 41, 319, 
44, 253, 314, 118, 16, 77, 435, 142, 416, 215, 93, 33, 181, 27, 
430, 89, 418, 290, 137, 437, 207, 245, 173, 118, 262, 117, 34, 
291, 164, 110, 330, 211, 367, 218, 106, 252, 227, 268, 130, 29, 
384, 424, 225, 390, 86, 85, 323, 350, 148, 332, 316, 138, 126, 
230, 175, 254, 223, 207, 328, 378, 258, 60, 410, 149, 152, 209, 
445, 409, 392), rain15 = c(347.83, 394.12, 382.2, 382.41, 395.7, 
386.08, 383.79, 352.65, 354.31, 366.48, 416.79, 335.17, 409.24, 
373, 390.76, 341.35, 387.25, 452.18, 329.14, 365.74, 432.58, 
443.36, 375.57, 359.75, 379.14, 386.41, 361.47, 366.1, 382.57, 
383.32, 409.56, 390.92, 380.38, 394.94, 366.72, 347.44, 336.88, 
410.94, 370.83, 335.88, 368.53, 370.42, 344.56, 323.41, 348.34, 
351.07, 382.75, 362.64, 402.7, 396.11, 418.01, 389.14, 462.76, 
391.05, 369.47, 399.78, 419.32, 392.97, 389.15, 345.37, 336.22, 
405.73, 378.45, 394.7, 388.29, 379.56, 437.29, 415.95, 388.91, 
402.43, 397.09, 368.84, 378.54, 361.92, 355.22, 416.46, 361.24, 
417.12, 420.92, 386.48, 375.04, 335.03, 385.23, 342.51, 401.27, 
341.21, 362.81, 372.85, 396.48, 390.72, 385.06, 343.64, 365.25, 
440.76, 364.68, 354.45, 368.7, 324.44, 366.4, 408.43, 405.71, 
390.8, 401.09, 364.07, 360.68, 399.39, 348.38, 344.2, 345.23, 
401.29, 356.48, 364.21, 376.12, 403.37, 384.1, 355.71, 389.53, 
363.28, 417.76, 403.16, 362.28, 333.91, 337.46, 419.51, 389.22, 
448.08, 338.46, 397.52, 372.25, 424.25, 349.25, 408.19, 376.68, 
375.87, 403.78, 398.73, 386.92, 340.39, 391.58, 335.03, 390.25, 
422.05, 423.79, 386.49, 392.97, 334.07, 403.85, 369.54, 348.84, 
392.33, 336.68, 399.56, 386.84, 395.97, 409.93, 337.08, 410.27, 
450.48, 364.93, 369.08, 413.31, 341.93, 360.06, 362.28, 395.8, 
423.56, 376.67, 366.19, 358.88, 390.74, 390.84, 362.84, 370.21, 
360.84, 371.9, 410.36, 421.59, 367.48, 355.62, 389.61, 370.81, 
374.37, 382.61, 401.78, 373.7, 382.72, 387.56, 388.53, 329.06, 
383.78, 336.97, 376.68, 398.57, 370.46, 388.88, 421.66, 369.29, 
371.58, 369.01, 369.22), YearsBurnt = c(6, 6, 3.5, 5, 3, 2, 3.5, 
2.5, 2, 1.5, 10.5, 3.5, 2.5, 3.5, 4.5, 3, 2, 2.5, 1.5, 3.5, 3.5, 
4, 4, 3, 3.5, 2.5, 6, 4.5, 4, 2.5, 3.5, 2, 7, 3, 2.5, 3.5, 13, 
3, 3.5, 3.5, 4.5, 3, 1.5, 2, 4, 2, 4.5, 4, 3.5, 2.5, 2, 2, 3, 
1, 5, 2.5, 4, 12.5, 2.5, 1.5, 3.5, 1.5, 2.5, 4, 4.5, 10, 3, 3.5, 
4.5, 10.5, 1, 4.5, 2, 13.5, 8.5, 10, 1, 4, 3, 3.5, 1.5, 3, 2.5, 
2.5, 2.5, 4.5, 4, 1.5, 3, 3.5, 4.5, 1.5, 3, 2.5, 3.5, 8.5, 4, 
7, 2.5, 5, 11, 3.5, 11.5, 3, 1.5, 3, 0.5, 4.5, 3.5, 13.5, 7.5, 
3.5, 2, 12, 4, 5, 2, 1.5, 3.5, 4.5, 2, 3.5, 3, 4, 1.5, 2, 2.5, 
6, 2, 5, 3.5, 4.5, 2, 3.5, 5, 4.5, 3, 4, 14, 3, 1.5, 3.5, 5.5, 
3, 4, 3, 7, 4.5, 2.5, 3, 3, 3.5, 3, 9, 5, 6.5, 5, 4, 4, 3.5, 
3, 8.5, 1, 4.5, 1.5, 5.5, 3, 2, 2.5, 2.5, 3, 8.5, 2.5, 1, 3.5, 
5.5, 5, 1.5, 2, 4.5, 5, 4, 1.5, 3.5, 4.5, 6, 4.5, 3.5, 3, 6.5, 
3, 6.5, 3.5, 4.5, 2.5, 2.5, 4, 4, 4, 4.5), YearsNotBurnt = c(9, 
9, 11.5, 10, 12, 13, 11.5, 12.5, 13, 13.5, 4.5, 11.5, 12.5, 11.5, 
10.5, 12, 13, 12.5, 13.5, 11.5, 11.5, 11, 11, 12, 11.5, 12.5, 
9, 10.5, 11, 12.5, 11.5, 13, 8, 12, 12.5, 11.5, 2, 12, 11.5, 
11.5, 10.5, 12, 13.5, 13, 11, 13, 10.5, 11, 11.5, 12.5, 13, 13, 
12, 14, 10, 12.5, 11, 2.5, 12.5, 13.5, 11.5, 13.5, 12.5, 11, 
10.5, 5, 12, 11.5, 10.5, 4.5, 14, 10.5, 13, 1.5, 6.5, 5, 14, 
11, 12, 11.5, 13.5, 12, 12.5, 12.5, 12.5, 10.5, 11, 13.5, 12, 
11.5, 10.5, 13.5, 12, 12.5, 11.5, 6.5, 11, 8, 12.5, 10, 4, 11.5, 
3.5, 12, 13.5, 12, 14.5, 10.5, 11.5, 1.5, 7.5, 11.5, 13, 3, 11, 
10, 13, 13.5, 11.5, 10.5, 13, 11.5, 12, 11, 13.5, 13, 12.5, 9, 
13, 10, 11.5, 10.5, 13, 11.5, 10, 10.5, 12, 11, 1, 12, 13.5, 
11.5, 9.5, 12, 11, 12, 8, 10.5, 12.5, 12, 12, 11.5, 12, 6, 10, 
8.5, 10, 11, 11, 11.5, 12, 6.5, 14, 10.5, 13.5, 9.5, 12, 13, 
12.5, 12.5, 12, 6.5, 12.5, 14, 11.5, 9.5, 10, 13.5, 13, 10.5, 
10, 11, 13.5, 11.5, 10.5, 9, 10.5, 11.5, 12, 8.5, 12, 8.5, 11.5, 
10.5, 12.5, 12.5, 11, 11, 11, 10.5), time = c(1.96, 4.94, 3.46, 
4.94, 2.73, 6.22, 4.5, 2.67, 4.66, 3.83, 0.38, 2.6, 3.97, 4.18, 
3.77, 3.44, 2.9, 3.93, 2.16, 3.51, 2.91, 3.19, 2.73, 6.36, 1.74, 
4.39, 4.1, 2.26, 2.36, 5.32, 1.74, 3.66, 1.26, 5.61, 9.04, 4.61, 
0.46, 3.98, 2.63, 5.5, 2.56, 5.92, 6.39, 2.26, 3.27, 7.95, 2.93, 
4.93, 2.97, 2.43, 5.91, 3.07, 4.27, 3.21, 4.12, 4.72, 1.93, 0.69, 
3.51, 4.39, 4.02, 3.18, 2.61, 4.61, 3.67, 0.54, 2.33, 2.93, 2.12, 
1.06, 3.95, 2.31, 5.44, 0.17, 1.42, 0.55, 8.35, 2.53, 2.91, 3.26, 
8.35, 2.26, 2.23, 7.18, 6.59, 6.36, 4.38, 7.67, 1.93, 3.34, 2.91, 
8.54, 5.75, 3.77, 2.63, 0.97, 3.27, 1.58, 7.18, 2.08, 0.69, 5.43, 
0.85, 2.26, 3.69, 3.18, 6.18, 2.93, 2.68, 0.69, 0.92, 2.34, 3.26, 
0.85, 2.91, 4.3, 3.95, 7.67, 2.93, 2.1, 6.54, 6.31, 3.87, 2.91, 
3.95, 3.35, 2.63, 1.49, 4.32, 3.51, 7.06, 2.67, 3.51, 3.46, 1.56, 
4.33, 5.64, 2.73, 0.57, 2.87, 3.69, 2.56, 2.33, 4.27, 4.73, 4.02, 
0.82, 4.11, 4.88, 2.29, 2.34, 3.72, 4.21, 1.49, 1.56, 3.03, 1.24, 
2.65, 5.71, 1.67, 2.71, 1.49, 3.95, 4.51, 3.36, 5.21, 4.18, 4.54, 
5.36, 4.25, 3.71, 0.95, 8.92, 3.12, 2.73, 1.36, 1.85, 7.24, 8.11, 
2.2, 0.95, 5.16, 1.3, 6.54, 3.01, 1.97, 2.91, 3.26, 3.72, 1.79, 
2.56, 1.96, 1.89, 1.89, 2.61, 5.25, 3.25, 5.26, 1.74, 3.73), 
    claylake = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 17.53, 0.1, 0.59, 0, 9.13, 36.93, 
    12.75, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.09, 0.01, 0, 0, 9.43, 74.71, 
    26.42, 0.23, 0, 0, 35.27, 74.71, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 20.81, 
    9.46, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    1.14, 0, 26.42, 3.62, 0, 0, 0, 0.21, 0, 0, 0, 0.03, 10.43, 
    0.99, 3.6, 5.32, 0, 0.36, 0, 0, 0.25, 0.01, 0.22, 0, 0, 6.45, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1.71, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 20.81, 0, 0, 0.18, 0, 
    0, 1.14, 0.03, 1.2, 0, 8.97, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1.14, 0, 1.56, 0.22, 
    1.2, 0, 0, 0.99, 0, 0, 0, 0, 4.14, 0, 0, 0.99, 0, 20.81, 
    0, 33.61, 0.09, 14.94, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.41, 0, 2.7, 0, 0.61, 
    8.97, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1.7, 2.67, 7.71, 0.2, 8.63, 1.56, 0, 0.49, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 11.9, 33.08, 0, 0, 0.99, 2.13, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0.03, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2.86, 1.65, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 60.14, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0.22, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 5.57
    ), spinsandplain = c(81.94, 34.29, 89.55, 34.29, 80.86, 75.92, 
    81.55, 43.53, 97.3, 87.84, 60.62, 80.81, 11.73, 5.11, 98.67, 
    79.52, 60.73, 91.65, 2.82, 97.31, 73.65, 72.78, 96.51, 74.02, 
    25.09, 50.74, 96.62, 88.77, 98.8, 54.04, 25.09, 95.1, 69.85, 
    99.4, 78.79, 78.77, 48.16, 80.68, 75.79, 66.33, 68.3, 79.11, 
    91.89, 82.49, 98.33, 90.82, 91.24, 65.01, 69.24, 99.94, 99.75, 
    18.57, 90.39, 95.56, 71.07, 67.85, 92.37, 85.85, 17.89, 50.74, 
    79.65, 68.82, 74.05, 78.77, 87.67, 41.11, 91.74, 91.24, 44.8, 
    86.24, 97.7, 94.17, 85.59, 33.53, 85.23, 94.55, 78.52, 95.49, 
    73.65, 95.04, 78.52, 82.49, 77.26, 83.4, 98.29, 85.24, 98.78, 
    87.09, 81.36, 96.62, 3.4, 94.65, 28.6, 98.67, 75.79, 73.34, 
    98.33, 74.88, 83.4, 88.24, 85.85, 52.44, 95.84, 82.49, 62.11, 
    98.74, 70.32, 86.18, 95.67, 85.85, 11.42, 85.96, 75.53, 95.84, 
    95.46, 93.68, 97.7, 87.09, 91.24, 80.03, 87.77, 68.71, 17.51, 
    95.46, 97.7, 50.7, 75.79, 70.43, 61.06, 97.31, 74.63, 99, 
    17.89, 89.55, 99.25, 98.08, 97.61, 93.36, 99.03, 38.1, 62.11, 
    96.9, 88.87, 40.48, 90.21, 73.79, 95.2, 66.53, 96.67, 82.89, 
    85.96, 97.08, 75.74, 70.43, 99.25, 96.4, 98.88, 98.13, 85.32, 
    54.19, 99.2, 81.42, 97.7, 82.25, 97.42, 98.1, 5.11, 12.06, 
    66.14, 52.39, 52.72, 12.32, 87.32, 98.95, 71.55, 90.58, 97.9, 
    80.62, 93.32, 76, 86.48, 86.42, 39.54, 68.65, 6.05, 86.02, 
    3.4, 75.53, 97.08, 32.47, 68.3, 81.94, 89.64, 57.4, 74.05, 
    0.47, 96.76, 86.7, 78.46, 84.81)), row.names = c(5208L, 2828L, 
1664L, 578L, 18L, 1644L, 4741L, 751L, 689L, 3813L, 1464L, 438L, 
1553L, 4752L, 4960L, 376L, 2482L, 1811L, 5682L, 5441L, 4505L, 
2281L, 2103L, 2993L, 562L, 4297L, 3592L, 5148L, 3793L, 1621L, 
1912L, 1627L, 1737L, 4976L, 2173L, 5132L, 5758L, 2756L, 1789L, 
5666L, 2628L, 2593L, 794L, 5779L, 5158L, 3123L, 4986L, 676L, 
4200L, 2442L, 2751L, 4330L, 1802L, 2020L, 2500L, 1056L, 959L, 
3290L, 4303L, 247L, 5586L, 922L, 1049L, 2432L, 2076L, 2560L, 
1369L, 3636L, 3722L, 4137L, 1561L, 4915L, 2515L, 3034L, 5547L, 
1491L, 1247L, 4116L, 455L, 4687L, 1697L, 5329L, 21L, 5724L, 3701L, 
5697L, 2938L, 1721L, 61L, 998L, 4304L, 5798L, 651L, 910L, 2689L, 
3986L, 2908L, 5753L, 2574L, 2345L, 1940L, 4317L, 4588L, 2179L, 
665L, 4133L, 749L, 3977L, 3134L, 4190L, 3985L, 4937L, 2473L, 
3238L, 4987L, 3915L, 4261L, 3521L, 2736L, 3665L, 1797L, 5692L, 
5578L, 4087L, 2011L, 903L, 889L, 1523L, 3396L, 2291L, 5269L, 
3644L, 3403L, 4814L, 4618L, 16L, 77L, 5385L, 2842L, 5816L, 2015L, 
1443L, 3183L, 3331L, 4977L, 5380L, 989L, 4918L, 740L, 4637L, 
887L, 1557L, 4295L, 4673L, 1918L, 5662L, 4167L, 1384L, 3441L, 
614L, 2360L, 780L, 661L, 1267L, 2018L, 1906L, 3402L, 677L, 5218L, 
2830L, 4979L, 3984L, 4924L, 1125L, 2640L, 986L, 1885L, 2573L, 
5300L, 2398L, 4832L, 4816L, 3738L, 3276L, 3830L, 2425L, 2054L, 
4273L, 5607L, 1678L, 378L, 1158L, 510L, 2210L, 2399L, 1952L, 
2909L, 4945L, 2659L, 2642L), class = "data.frame")
```

I create a new variable as the proportion of years burnt is out of 15 years (i.e., binomial)

```
data$fireprop = cbind(data$YearsBurnt,data$YearsNotBurnt)
```

[image]

Model:

```
mfireprop = glmer(fireprop~log(time)+spinsandplain+rain15+claylake+rain15*log(time)+(1|circleID),na.action=na.fail, family=binomial, data=data)
```

Trend line code:

```
d = ggpredict(mfireprop, terms = "time[exp]")
d = rename(d, "time" = x, "fireprop" = predicted)
ggplot(d, aes(time, fireprop)) + 
  geom_ribbon(aes(ymin = conf.low, ymax = conf.high), alpha = .1) +
  geom_line(size = 2, colour = "black") + 
  theme_bw()
```

And the trend line comes out looking like this:

[image]

Why is the x axis not stopping at 10 hours where the data stops? Why is it going to 20,000? And why does the y axis only go to 0.4? When some of the proportions are 1?

When I limit the x and y axis it ends up looking like this:

[image]

But when I look at the raw data over the top of that, it seems like the trend line is starting off in a really odd place.

[image]

I am unsure of what I am doing wrong?

Comment: With the data that you've supplied, I can't get the model you ran to fit. Would you be able to give more of the data so I can?

Comment: Hello, yes sure - is there another R function that would allow me to still summarise the data, but give you more of it?

Comment: If you can paste the output of `dput(df)` that might help

Comment: I cant seem to post that because I go over the character limit, is there a way around that do you know? Sorry!

Comment: I would randomly subset 200 rows or so of the data frame with something like `example <- df[sample(nrow(df), 200),]` a few times until you can reproduce your problem with the example. Then I'd round the data to two or three decimal points like this: `example$x <- round(example$x, digits=2)`, then I would run `dput(example)` and there should be space

Comment: I have done as you suggested. Maybe its something to do with the error warning message: "non-integer counts in a binomial glm!" ???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, so I've figured out the main problem here. In the documentation of the `ggpredict()` function there is an argument called `back.transform` that defaults to TRUE. This means that log-transformed data will be automatically transformed back to the original response scale. This is why if you examine the ggpredict object `d`, you will see that the `time` variable actually does go to over 8000 in that object. So because you did not flag `back.transform=FALSE`, but also specified `time[exp]`, what happened was the function automatically exponentiated your values, and then you did it again.

If we look at the logged values:

```
summary(log(data$time))
   Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max. 
-1.7720  0.8154  1.1802  1.0904  1.4793  2.2017
```

Then we exponentiate the max value, we get the previous max:

```
exp(2.2017) # Exponentiated to get back to years
[1] 9.040369

summary(df$time) # The original variable
   Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max. 
  0.170   2.260   3.255   3.519   4.390   9.040
```

If we exponentiate it again, we end up with the max time being over 8000.

```
exp(9.040369)
[1] 8436.89
```

So, to get the plot you want, you just need to leave out the [exp] after calling time in `ggpredict()`:

```
d = ggpredict(mfireprop, terms = "time")
d = rename(d, "time" = x, "fireprop" = predicted)

ggplot(d, aes(time, fireprop)) + 
  geom_ribbon(aes(ymin = conf.low, ymax = conf.high), alpha = .1) +
  geom_line(size = 2, colour = "black") + 
  theme_bw()
```

[image]

The time is being cut off because at time 0 there is no variation. `YearsNotBurnt` is always 0. Therefore, if you look at the object `d` from ggpredict, you will see `NaN` in all the columns for time 0. If you simplify the model to the following:

```
mfireprop2 = glmer(fireprop~
                    log(time) +
                    (1|circleID),
                  na.action=na.fail, 
                  family=binomial, 
                  data=df)
```

You will be able to get the plot, but because there is very little variation, the confidence interval will span from one to zero. I believe this is an issue related to separation, basically it means that binomial models can't be fit in frequentist models if there is no variation, or if something perfectly predicts the outcome.

[image]

The only I think I wanted to mention is that you had a question in the comments about "non-integer counts in a binomial glm!". This is because it expects the dependent variable to be a proportion of trials, which should not have decimals. You have points in your data that seem to be half-year intervals. I'm not familiar with your data enough to say for sure what a better alternative would be, but creating a proportion and giving the number of observations in the `weights=` argument might be an option.

Comment: Hmm very interesting, thank you for your answer. You seem to hit the nail on the head, I'll have to explore this further. Thanks!

Comment: No problem, glad to help!